# PHP5- instanceof/is_a failure?

Tags: php, types

I've got this code in PHP5

```
<?php
function debug_log($log) {
    echo $log;
}
// Supporting classes
class Tag {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $tagname;
    private $extras;
    public function __construct($tag) {
        $this->id = 0; // Set to non-zero if you want an id
        $this->name = ''; // Set to non-empty for a name
        $this->tagname = $tag; // This is what tag, e.g. select/html/head
        $this->extras = ''; // If we need anything extra that isn't covered
    }
    protected function OpenTag() {
        debug_log('Tag::OpenTag()');
        $html = '<' . $this->tagname;
        if ($this->id != 0) {
            $html .= 'id = ' . $this->id;
        }
        if ($this->name != '') {
            $html .= 'name = ' . $this->name;
        }
        if ($this->extras != '') {
            $html .= ' ' . $this->extra;
        }
        $html .= '>';
        echo $html;
    }
    protected function CloseTag() {
        debug_log('Tag::CloseTag()');
        $html = '</' . $this->tagname . '>';
        echo $html;
    }
    public function ID($new_id) {
        $this->id = $new_id;
        return $this;
    }
    public function Name($new_name) {
        $this->name = $new_name;
        return $this;
    }
    public function Extras($newextras) {
        $this->extras = $newextras;
        return $this;
    }
    public function Emit() {
        Tag::OpenTag();
        Tag::CloseTag();
    }
}
// Unfortunately, totally necessary.
function MakeTag($arg) {
    return new Tag($arg);
}

class ContentTag extends Tag {
    private $tags;
    public function __construct($tagname) {
        parent::__construct($tagname);
        $this->tags = array();
    }
    public function AddTag($tag) {
        array_push($this->tags, $tag);
        return $tag;
    }
    public function Emit() {
        debug_log('In ContentTag::Emit()');
        Tag::OpenTag();
        debug_log('Emitting ' . count($this->tags) . ' tags.');
        for($i = 0; $i < count($this->tags); $i++) {
            if (is_a($this->tags[i], "Tag")) {
                echo 'Emitting a tag - ';
                $this->tags[i]->Emit();
            } else {
                echo 'Not emitting a tag of type '. get_class($this->tags[i]);
                echo (string)$this->tags[i];
            }
        }
        Tag::CloseTag();
    }
}
function MakeContentTag($arg) {
    return new ContentTag($arg);
}
class Listbox extends Tag {
    private $options;
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('select');
        $this->options = array();
        $this->name = '';
    }
    public function AddOption($name) {
        array_push($this->options, $name);
    }
    public function SetName($new_name) {
        $this->name = $new_name;
    }
    public function Emit() {
        OpenTag();
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->options); $i++) {
            $innerHTML = $innerHTML . '<option>' . $options[i] . '</option>';
        }        
        echo $innerHTML;
        CloseTag();
    }
}
class Title extends Tag {
    private $title;
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('title');
    }
    public function SetTitle($newtitle) {
        $this->title = $newtitle;
    }
    public function Emit() {
        OpenTag();
        echo $this->title;
        CloseTag();
    }
}
class Link extends Tag {
    private $href;
    private $rel;
    private $type;
    private function AddExtras() {
        Tag::Extras('href=' . $href . ' rel=' . $rel . ' type=' . $type);      
    }
    public function __construct($ahref, $arel, $atype) {
        parent::__construct('link');
        $this->href = $ahref;
        $this->rel = $arel;
        $this->type = $atype;
        $this->AddExtras();
    }
    public function Href() {
        return $this->href;
    }
    public function Rel() {
        return $this->rel;
    }
    public function Type() {
        return $this->type;
    }
    public function SetType($atype) {
        $this->type = $atype;
        $this->AddExtras();
        return $this;
    }
    public function SetHref($ahref) {
        $this->href = $ahref;
        $this->AddExtras();
        return $this;
    }
    public function SetRel($arel) {
        $this->rel = $arel;
        $this->AddExtras();
        return $this;
    }

}
function MakeLink($a, $b, $c) {
    return new Link($a, $b, $c);
}
class Img extends Tag {
    public function __construct($src, $alt) {
        parent::__construct('img');
        Tag::Extras('src=' . $src . ' alt=' . $alt);
    }
}
class DOM extends ContentTag {
    private $body;
    private $head;
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('html');
        Tag::Extras('xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"');
        $this->head = new ContentTag('head');
        $this->body = new ContentTag('body');
        $this->AddTag($this->head);
        $this->AddTag($this->body);
        $this->head->AddTag(MakeTag('meta')->Extras('http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"'));
    }
    public function Head() {
        return $this->head;
    }
    public function Body() {
        return $this->head;
    }
    public function Emit() {
        echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">';
        ContentTag::Emit();
    }
}

// top.php
$pagediv = 0;
$view = new DOM();
$view->Head()->AddTag(MakeLink('css/style.css', 'stylesheet', 'text/css'));
$view->Head()->AddTag(MakeLink('favicon.ico', 'icon', 'image/x-icon'));
$view->Head()->AddTag(MakeContentTag('div')->ID('top_grad'));
$div = $view->Body()->AddTag(MakeContentTag('div')->Extras('align="center"'));
$topdiv = $div->AddTag(MakeContentTag('div')->ID('top'));
$topdiv->AddTag(MakeContentTag('div')->ID('logo'))->AddTag(new Img('images/loughborough-logo.png', 'Loughborough University'));
$topdiv->AddTag(MakeContentTag('div')->ID('title'))->AddTag('TimeTable System');
$topdiv->AddTag(MakeContentTag('div')->ID('roundnumber')->Extras('align="right"'))->AddTag('Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '</br>' . 'Round Number: 1');
$page = $topdiv->AddTag(MakeContentTag('div')->ID('page'));
$view->Emit();
?>
```

It's quite a bit of code, but frankly, I'm just not sure what to post. The ContentTag::Emit method is failing. Specifically, variables inside `$tags` are failing the `instanceof Tag` check, even though they are of type `ContentTag`, and `get_class` confirms this. But if I remove the check and Emit anyway, then it says that Emit does not exist- even though I just confirmed using `get_class` that those variables are of type ContentTag. The *quantity* is correct, so I'm pretty sure that all the preceeding code is correct too. I've also changed between `is_a` and `instanceof` and they both exhibit the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue i have is with you forgetting your `$` variable tokens on the increment value `i` in your loops:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  i in dom.php on line 74
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in dom.php on line 78
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  i in dom.php on line 78
Not emitting a tag of type PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in dom.php on line 79
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  i in /dom.php on line 79
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' dom.php on line 74
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  i in dom.php on line 74
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in dom.php on line 78
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  i in dom.php on line 78
Not emitting a tag of type PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in dom.php on line 79
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  i in dom.php on line 79
```

Comment: So glad that I'm never going anywhere near this sinkhole of a language when this project is finished. Thanks!

Comment: Haha... well i cant really agree witht hat sentiment... its my bread and butter :-)

Comment: @DeadMG: While I understand your frustration, *only a poor craftsman blames his tools*.  It's up to you to learn how to use your tools in order to be able to use them effectively...

Comment: @ircmaxwell: What tools? There are no tools for PHP. There are only outdated links to software that no longer works, with manual installation and such. Compared to Java, C# or C++. None of those languages would ever spend time debugging problems like this. That's like saying that I should be able to craft with my bare hands the same as a billion dollar factory.

Comment: @DeadMG: IT took me a couple minutes to figure out the problem... all i did was look at the default error messages... no debugger or anything required - there were pretty explicit. And there are tons of tools.. debuggers: XDebug, Zend Debug... IDEs: Eclipse, NetBeans, Aptana, PHPEd... as far as installation pretty much every nix environment has some kind of package manager... I work on Mac so i use the macports, but there are up to date dists in yum, rpm, apt, and port repositories... There is Also Zend Server Community edition...

Comment: I dont fault you for not liking the lang... many dont - but i do fault you for your reasoning :-)

Comment: @DeadMG seems that you are working without turning on E_NOTICE error notification. Locate your php.ini file, search for the `error_reporting` setting and set it to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` (or just E_ALL if you are using php >= 5.3). Also check that `display_errors = On`. **NOTE**: On production machines, set `display_errors = Off`, leave that on just for development machines.

Comment: @Carlos: That only works if I own and have access to the servers, which I don't. I upload a script, it doesn't work, that's all I got. @prodigitalson: I followed some links posted in the PHP chatroom. It's about five installs, some of which are manual, and the result definitely did not work. Compare to, install Visual Studio, and done, for C++.

Comment: Then, if `display_errors = On` in php.ini, you may change the `error_reporting` level by using `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` in your php code. Also, according to [documentation](http://php.net/display-errors) you may change `display_errors` with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Path of least resistance: [Eclipse+PDT/Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt) I never use Zend Server myself, but its got a full installer and admin GUI so its probably a good option for you since you have little experience with PHP. Set this up on your **local** workstaion and develop locally. Then deploy to the server to test, then move it in to production. All the errors youve made are pretty much syntax mistakes... which should be caught before you ever put anything on the server to test...